# Default selections and subsequent print of the selected values outputs as an error console

Tags: angular

I have a selection list below which i want to get the complete json object as value. By default i am selecting the first item.

```
 <mat-selection-list [multiple]="false" #productItem>
        <mat-list-option
          *ngFor="let item of product.productDetails; let i = index"
          [selected]="i === 0"
          [value]="item"
          >{{ item.unit }} {{ item.measurement }}</mat-list-option
        >
      </mat-selection-list>
```

I am displaying the price according the list value changes.

```
<h4>
        {{
          productItem.selectedOptions.selected[0]?.value.price | currency: "INR"
        }}
      </h4>
```

The data is showing as i expected. However when i look at the console, i have following error

core.js:4081 ERROR Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'null'. Current value: '400'.

Is there any better way of getting this data?

Comment: put the code where you are getting product.productDetails in setTimeOut block

Comment: Can you suggest me with the code changes? Thanks in advance

Comment: need to see your ts file

Comment: product information comes as an input. export class ProductItemComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() product: IProduct;